# how to change label of nextpage and previouspage in bootstrap pagination?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I change label of nextpage and previouspage in bootstrap pagination? 
for example in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKqi4NBFvNc6oAObIYO4?p=preview) sample how can I write `pushNext` instead of `nextpage`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
previous-text (Default: 'Previous') : Text for Previous button.

next-text (Default: 'Next') : Text for Next button.
```

All is described in the doc http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Go to pagination